# using .htaccess to deny an IP address

Tags: .htaccess, network-programming, ip

So i have everything set up correctly.

### By default allow all access

```
    order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.111.0.11
```

---

my public ip: 2600:8801:db06:3a00:c85b:516d:5dc1:7f7d
Your public IP address

When i set my ip address from work... everything is fine.. but when i try and do my home network.. cox.. it doesn't work and it keeps telling me i don't have authorization to view the page... exactly what it should do if it was the wrong IP.

Sorry for the stupid question.. this is bugging me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You want to allow your home IP as well? `allow from 2600:8801:db06:3a00:c85b:516d:5dc1:7f7d`

Comment: tried it already and it didn't work

Comment: Where are you getting your IP from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.111.0.11
Allow from 2600:8801:db06:3a00:c85b:516d:5dc1:7f7d
```

Comment: Okay, i'll give it a shot when i'm home later. Thank you.